# Although all is correct, Linux kernel module signing fails strangely

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have a problem during signing kernel module, which is not able to sign microcodes only, other is going well.

```
/playground/lin/linux$ make bindeb-pkg KBUILD_SIGN_PIN=1234 -j8 V=12 1> /dev/null 0> /dev/null
 dpkg-source --before-build .
 make -f debian/rules binary
+ [ ld = clean ]
+ make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=init init/version-timestamp.o
+ btf_vmlinux_bin_o=
+ is_enabled CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y include/config/auto.conf
+ kallsymso=
+ kallsymso_prev=
+ kallsyms_vmlinux=
+ is_enabled CONFIG_KALLSYMS
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y include/config/auto.conf
+ kallsyms_step 1
+ kallsymso_prev=
+ kallsyms_vmlinux=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1
+ kallsymso=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.o
+ kallsyms_S=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.S
+ vmlinux_link .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1 
+ local output=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1
+ local objs
+ local libs
+ local ld
+ local ldflags
+ local ldlibs
+ info LD .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1
+ printf   %-7s %s\n LD .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1
+ shift
+ is_enabled CONFIG_LTO_CLANG
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_LTO_CLANG=y include/config/auto.conf
+ is_enabled CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT=y include/config/auto.conf
+ objs=vmlinux.a
+ libs=
+ is_enabled CONFIG_MODULES
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_MODULES=y include/config/auto.conf
+ objs=vmlinux.a .vmlinux.export.o
+ objs=vmlinux.a .vmlinux.export.o init/version-timestamp.o
+ [ x86 = um ]
+ wl=
+ ld=ld
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn
+ ldlibs=
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds
+ [ .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1 != 1 ]
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds --strip-debug
+ is_enabled CONFIG_VMLINUX_MAP
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_VMLINUX_MAP=y include/config/auto.conf
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds --strip-debug -Map=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.map
+ ld -m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds --strip-debug -Map=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.map -o .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1 --whole-archive vmlinux.a .vmlinux.export.o init/version-timestamp.o --no-whole-archive --start-group --end-group
+ mksysmap .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1 .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.syms
+ info NM .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.syms
+ printf   %-7s %s\n NM .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.syms
+ sh ./scripts/mksysmap .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1 .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.syms
+ kallsyms .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.syms .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.S
+ local kallsymopt
+ is_enabled CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL=y include/config/auto.conf
+ kallsymopt= --all-symbols
+ is_enabled CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ABSOLUTE_PERCPU
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ABSOLUTE_PERCPU=y include/config/auto.conf
+ kallsymopt= --all-symbols --absolute-percpu
+ is_enabled CONFIG_KALLSYMS_BASE_RELATIVE
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_KALLSYMS_BASE_RELATIVE=y include/config/auto.conf
+ kallsymopt= --all-symbols --absolute-percpu --base-relative
+ is_enabled CONFIG_LTO_CLANG
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_LTO_CLANG=y include/config/auto.conf
+ info KSYMS .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.S
+ printf   %-7s %s\n KSYMS .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.S
+ scripts/kallsyms --all-symbols --absolute-percpu --base-relative .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.syms
+ info AS .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.S
+ printf   %-7s %s\n AS .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.S
+ gcc -nostdinc -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -D__ASSEMBLY__ -fno-PIE -m64 -DCC_USING_FENTRY -g -gdwarf-5 -c -o .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.o .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.S
+ kallsyms_step 2
+ kallsymso_prev=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.o
+ kallsyms_vmlinux=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2
+ kallsymso=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.o
+ kallsyms_S=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.S
+ vmlinux_link .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2 .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.o
+ local output=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2
+ local objs
+ local libs
+ local ld
+ local ldflags
+ local ldlibs
+ info LD .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2
+ printf   %-7s %s\n LD .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2
+ shift
+ is_enabled CONFIG_LTO_CLANG
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_LTO_CLANG=y include/config/auto.conf
+ is_enabled CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT=y include/config/auto.conf
+ objs=vmlinux.a
+ libs=
+ is_enabled CONFIG_MODULES
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_MODULES=y include/config/auto.conf
+ objs=vmlinux.a .vmlinux.export.o
+ objs=vmlinux.a .vmlinux.export.o init/version-timestamp.o
+ [ x86 = um ]
+ wl=
+ ld=ld
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn
+ ldlibs=
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds
+ [ .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2 != 2 ]
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds --strip-debug
+ is_enabled CONFIG_VMLINUX_MAP
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_VMLINUX_MAP=y include/config/auto.conf
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds --strip-debug -Map=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.map
+ ld -m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds --strip-debug -Map=.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.map -o .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2 --whole-archive vmlinux.a .vmlinux.export.o init/version-timestamp.o --no-whole-archive --start-group --end-group .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.o
+ mksysmap .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2 .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.syms .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.o
+ info NM .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.syms
+ printf   %-7s %s\n NM .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.syms
+ sh ./scripts/mksysmap .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2 .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.syms .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.o
+ kallsyms .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.syms .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.S
+ local kallsymopt
+ is_enabled CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL=y include/config/auto.conf
+ kallsymopt= --all-symbols
+ is_enabled CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ABSOLUTE_PERCPU
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ABSOLUTE_PERCPU=y include/config/auto.conf
+ kallsymopt= --all-symbols --absolute-percpu
+ is_enabled CONFIG_KALLSYMS_BASE_RELATIVE
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_KALLSYMS_BASE_RELATIVE=y include/config/auto.conf
+ kallsymopt= --all-symbols --absolute-percpu --base-relative
+ is_enabled CONFIG_LTO_CLANG
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_LTO_CLANG=y include/config/auto.conf
+ info KSYMS .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.S
+ printf   %-7s %s\n KSYMS .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.S
+ scripts/kallsyms --all-symbols --absolute-percpu --base-relative .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.syms
+ info AS .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.S
+ printf   %-7s %s\n AS .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.S
+ gcc -nostdinc -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -D__ASSEMBLY__ -fno-PIE -m64 -DCC_USING_FENTRY -g -gdwarf-5 -c -o .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.o .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.S
+ sh ./scripts/file-size.sh .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.o
+ size1=4656736
+ sh ./scripts/file-size.sh .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.o
+ size2=4656736
+ [ 4656736 -ne 4656736 ]
+ [ -n  ]
+ vmlinux_link vmlinux .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.o
+ local output=vmlinux
+ local objs
+ local libs
+ local ld
+ local ldflags
+ local ldlibs
+ info LD vmlinux
+ printf   %-7s %s\n LD vmlinux
+ shift
+ is_enabled CONFIG_LTO_CLANG
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_LTO_CLANG=y include/config/auto.conf
+ is_enabled CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT=y include/config/auto.conf
+ objs=vmlinux.a
+ libs=
+ is_enabled CONFIG_MODULES
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_MODULES=y include/config/auto.conf
+ objs=vmlinux.a .vmlinux.export.o
+ objs=vmlinux.a .vmlinux.export.o init/version-timestamp.o
+ [ x86 = um ]
+ wl=
+ ld=ld
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn
+ ldlibs=
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds
+ [ vmlinux != vmlinux ]
+ is_enabled CONFIG_VMLINUX_MAP
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_VMLINUX_MAP=y include/config/auto.conf
+ ldflags=-m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds -Map=vmlinux.map
+ ld -m elf_x86_64 -z noexecstack -z max-page-size=0x200000 --build-id=sha1 --orphan-handling=warn --script=./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds -Map=vmlinux.map -o vmlinux --whole-archive vmlinux.a .vmlinux.export.o init/version-timestamp.o --no-whole-archive --start-group --end-group .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.o
+ is_enabled CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y include/config/auto.conf
+ mksysmap vmlinux System.map .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.o
+ info NM System.map
+ printf   %-7s %s\n NM System.map
+ sh ./scripts/mksysmap vmlinux System.map .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.o
+ is_enabled CONFIG_BUILDTIME_TABLE_SORT
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_BUILDTIME_TABLE_SORT=y include/config/auto.conf
+ info SORTTAB vmlinux
+ printf   %-7s %s\n SORTTAB vmlinux
+ sorttable vmlinux
+ ./scripts/sorttable vmlinux
+ is_enabled CONFIG_KALLSYMS
+ grep -q ^CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y include/config/auto.conf
+ cmp -s System.map .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.syms
+ echo vmlinux: scripts/link-vmlinux.sh
At main.c:298:
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
sign-file: - SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/events/amd/amd-uncore.ko
debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/mce-inject.ko
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/events/intel/intel-cstate.ko
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/events/rapl.ko
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/events/amd/amd-uncore.ko] 오류 1
make[6]: *** 끝나지 않은 작업을 기다리고 있습니다....
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/mce-inject.ko] 오류 1
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/events/rapl.ko] 오류 1
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/events/intel/intel-cstate.ko] 오류 1
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-x86_64.ko
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-x86_64-3way.ko
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-x86_64.ko] 오류 1
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-x86_64-3way.ko] 오류 1
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-avx-x86_64.ko
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/serpent-sse2-x86_64.ko
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-avx-x86_64.ko] 오류 1
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:137: debian/linux-image/lib/modules/6.7.41+/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/serpent-sse2-x86_64.ko] 오류 1
make[5]: *** [Makefile:1819: modules_install] 오류 2
make[4]: *** [Makefile:2034: run-command] 오류 2
make[3]: *** [debian/rules:17: binary-arch] 오류 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: make -f debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:144: bindeb-pkg] 오류 2
make[1]: *** [/playground/lin/linux/Makefile:1535: bindeb-pkg] 오류 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] 오류 2
```

As above, It prints mysterious errors.

Information with its certificate(passphrase is '1234') ;

```
/playground/lin/linux$ openssl x509 -in ../certs/lemon.pem -key ../certs/lemon.pem -noout -text 
Enter pass phrase for ../certs/lemon.pem:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            14:a0:3d:c9:62:cd:53:29:63:c2:76:28:a9:70:fb:f8:00:fb:31:bc
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = KR, ST = Seoul, L = Yong-san, O = None, OU = None, CN = Stranger, emailAddress = None
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb 21 10:30:39 2024 GMT
            Not After : Mar 22 10:30:39 2024 GMT
        Subject: C = KR, ST = Seoul, L = Yong-san, O = None, OU = None, CN = Stranger, emailAddress = None
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d5:95:48:db:5f:76:6d:33:3c:ac:2d:dd:0e:02:
                    ab:64:3c:aa:71:d1:84:a3:a3:af:51:37:2e:26:75:
                    79:38:df:7f:89:59:01:30:5f:a0:a0:3d:eb:cd:c5:
                    5c:f7:b9:42:06:cd:2a:22:bd:16:84:fc:f6:e9:62:
                    2f:68:11:83:5f:c9:17:94:24:ba:ae:a7:66:f6:de:
                    19:4f:63:36:e0:76:e0:be:66:40:71:69:41:e7:e1:
                    96:a0:ea:8a:6d:34:25:7e:8f:df:1b:4b:d5:ec:54:
                    ee:48:11:88:51:fc:62:f6:d0:e6:7c:86:60:d6:32:
                    0e:34:b8:5b:e0:eb:55:64:75:a6:85:da:bb:d7:b5:
                    0f:c8:a4:ea:cd:73:85:0c:cb:d4:16:fb:c6:e6:53:
                    c3:8a:3a:e1:70:61:99:27:09:21:23:5f:91:58:3c:
                    28:fd:19:51:f9:d6:8a:8b:9d:15:a9:0c:64:78:e8:
                    08:69:b5:48:4f:63:5f:a5:90:71:be:9a:ff:fc:8c:
                    92:8c:31:bb:24:5a:bc:02:18:eb:73:d7:36:67:16:
                    55:da:c6:c6:93:da:35:d6:21:33:6c:07:92:60:f5:
                    8c:67:cc:b1:a9:7d:e5:a5:69:1a:bc:85:1d:c0:d7:
                    65:9e:10:ef:cd:60:9c:47:94:81:53:f8:bf:f1:5b:
                    cd:07
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                EA:E5:A4:B6:01:D7:3D:A5:7C:65:29:50:90:C7:AB:EE:2E:20:1B:84
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                EA:E5:A4:B6:01:D7:3D:A5:7C:65:29:50:90:C7:AB:EE:2E:20:1B:84
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        4c:ba:eb:51:d9:7a:4e:57:5b:1b:f3:59:10:8c:ac:be:f9:f9:
        e0:c7:d8:5b:b2:4e:be:38:da:35:06:ff:4c:66:b0:8e:30:3f:
        f6:31:8a:c1:8f:0e:0b:1d:5c:50:ee:4e:88:17:02:ef:e0:98:
        93:58:68:6a:df:48:3f:ce:d8:f5:2e:18:aa:09:02:96:a6:ad:
        d2:42:e4:90:e8:ac:99:11:28:6f:be:01:71:43:ad:79:83:2b:
        b6:99:7f:c8:4e:e0:48:20:2c:7d:c3:b7:7a:91:eb:03:2b:07:
        c9:24:9b:f1:84:0b:62:69:1d:bc:9b:38:b3:c0:c4:5d:b6:98:
        0a:50:a1:f0:92:e4:f8:81:2a:f0:05:1a:e7:bc:fc:ac:34:9f:
        26:e2:da:6f:60:47:49:36:17:52:6e:9d:88:17:5e:d1:85:08:
        23:e6:81:87:ee:44:e5:32:3c:2b:0b:ef:6e:8e:83:42:fb:87:
        77:7b:4f:a0:3b:6e:7b:45:40:ae:0f:23:90:7e:e3:39:6f:81:
        ee:27:44:81:7c:ca:8b:ec:fa:6a:97:19:e1:fc:78:07:9b:96:
        d6:03:76:d3:99:0e:6d:17:ea:82:b4:12:48:e6:52:16:cc:9a:
        ea:c1:d4:28:13:ad:c1:12:8b:e2:d4:6c:f1:dd:5a:70:57:03:
        e9:38:b1:b1
```

And, configurations concerning the issue;
[image]

Comment: If that is the cert you are using to sign the modules with, then it is missing the `code signing` extension (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3).